# It is possible to getting stuck in the compare_exchange's loop?

Tags: c++, atomic, gcc9

Consider this code (from *'C++ concurrency in action' [Second edition]: page 212*):

```cpp
void LockFreeStack::pop (stack_data& result)
{
    Node* old_head = head.load();
    while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next))
        ;
    result = old_head->data;
}
```

I think it's possible to thread-one execute `pop()` and after executing first line (loading `head`) time slicing happened to thread-two, which is executing `push(T&)`. So now value of `head` atomic variable is not equal to `old_head` and `while`-loop won't break.
It's right ?

Comment: `compare_exchange_weak` updates its first parameter to match the second. That's what breaks the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `head` is a `std::atomic<Node*>` then the code is correct as when [`compare_exchange_weak`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) fails it loads the current value of the variable into its first parameter, after the `compare_exchange_weak` call `old_head` will always contain the current value of `head`.

The code is roughly equivalent to doing the following without atomics:

```
Node* old_head = head;
while (true)
{
  std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
  if (old_head == head)
  {
     head = old_head->next;
     break;
  }
  else
  {
     old_head = head;
  }
}
```

Concurrent calls to `pop` are therefore safe and shouldn't block forever (other than due to other threads constantly calling pop and somehow always setting the value before the current thread gets a chance).

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by @Alan Birtles, you will not be stuck in the while-loop. However, it is important to note that your code will most likely suffer from the ABA problem. Consider to the following scenario:

- the stack looks like this: `A->B->C` (i.e., head points to A)
- thread 1 loads the head (i.e., the address of `A`) and `A`'s next pointer (`B`), but before it can perform the CAS, it is interrupted.
- thread 2 pops `A`, then `B`, and then pushes `A`, i.e., the stack now looks like this: `A->C`
- thread 1 resumes and happily updates the head from `A` to `B` -> *boom!*

There are several possible solutions to avoid the ABA problem, like tagged pointers or concurrent memory reclamation schemes.